# The car bounced/bumped over something

Tags: word-choice, difference

> He was about to take a sip of his coffee when suddenly his car bounced/bumped over something.

Could anyone please tell me the difference between "bounced" and "bumped" here? Are both okay? When to use what?

Comment: A bounce implies that the car was impelled into the air after striking an impediment, which is possible at high speed. A bump indicates that the car merely struck and rose over the impediment. A tennis ball bounces along. A slow-moving car bumps along an uneven road.

Answer (score 0):

"Bump" can mean a few different things related to driving:

1. A *collision* - eg. *the car bumped into a lorry*.
2. A *raised area or surface* - eg. *the car hit a bump in the road*
3. To *travel over a rough surface* - eg. *the car bumped along the road*.

That third [definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bump) means to *continuously* drive over a bumpy road and doesn't quite fit with your scenario of hitting a single bump - still native speakers *do* say both "bumped over" and "bounced over". This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=car%20bounced%20over%2C%20car%20bumped%20over&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccar%20bounced%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccar%20bumped%20over%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccar%20bounced%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccar%20bumped%20over%3B%2Cc0) shows that both appear to be used almost equally over time.

Alternatively, you could say:

- suddenly his car hit a bump.
- suddenly his car bounced as the wheels hit a bump.